# Apple Test Flight app available to actual users

Tags: app-store, testflight, beta-testing

Our Environment

1. Expo React Native, Expo for Build, We are not using expo-updates.
2. Apple Test Flight for beta testing
3. Microsoft Endpoint Manager for managing devices/iPads.

·       On 4/1 morning we had app store version 2.0.5 and Test Flight version 2.0.6. Many users who use company managed devices/ipad reported that they can see the new
features which were available only in test flight (2.0.6) which caused some issues for users.

·       On 4/1 afternoon We created and submitted a Hot fix (rollback) 2.0.7 which was approved in app store on 4/2.

·       Since we have rolled it back to 2.0.7 we don't have a screen shot available but we know it happened because many users reported issues

·       I am not sure how on 4/1 test flight version (2.0.6)  got Installed to users devices?

Comment: Were those users part of your App Store Connect team?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out very next day. We were getting over the air updates from Expo build.
I disabled Expo OTA updates and submitted new version to app store.